# Obtain tf-idf weights of words with sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, nlp, tf-idf

I have a set of texts of wikipedia.
Using **tf-idf**, I can define the weight of each word.
Below is the code:

```
import pandas as pd                                             
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

wiki = pd.read_csv('people_wiki.csv')

tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(max_features= 1000000)
tfidf = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(wiki['text'])
```

The goal is to see the weights like shown in the **tf-idf** column:

[image]

The file 'people_wiki.csv' is here:

https://ufile.io/udg1y

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`TfidfVectorizer` has a `vocabulary_` attribute which is very useful for what you want. This attribute is dictionary with words as keys and the corresponding column index that word has as value.

For the below example I want the inverse of that dictionary for that I use a dictionary comprehension.

```
tfidf_vec = TfidfVectorizer()
transformed = tfidf_vec.fit_transform(raw_documents=['this is a quick example','just to show off'])
index_value={i[1]:i[0] for i in tfidf_vec.vocabulary_.items()}
```

`index_value` will be used as a lookup table further on.

`fit_transform` returns a Compressed Sparse Row format matrix. The attributes which are useful for what you want to achieve are `indices` and `data`. `indices` returns all the indices that actually contain data and `data` returns all the data in those indices.

Looping over the returned `transformed` sparse matrix as follows.

```
fully_indexed = []
for row in transformed:
    fully_indexed.append({index_value[column]:value for (column,value) in zip(row.indices,row.data)})
```

returns a list of dictionaries with the following contents.

```
[{'example': 0.5, 'is': 0.5, 'quick': 0.5, 'this': 0.5},
 {'just': 0.5, 'off': 0.5, 'show': 0.5, 'to': 0.5}]
```

Please note that doing it this way only returns words that have a non zero value for a specific document. Looking at the first document in my example there is no `'just', 0.0` key value pair in the dictionary. If you want to include those you need to tweak the final dictionary comprehension a bit.

Like so

```
fully_indexed = []
transformed = np.array(transformed.todense())
for row in transformed:
    fully_indexed.append({index_value[column]:value for (column,value) in enumerate(row)})
```

We create a dense version of the matrix as a numpy array loop over each row of the numpy array enumerate the contents and then fill the list of dictionaries. 
Doing it this way results in output that also includes all words that were not present in a document.

```
[{'example': 0.5,'is': 0.5,'just': 0.0,'off': 0.0,'quick': 0.5,'show': 0.0,'this': 0.5,'to': 0.0},
 {'example': 0.0,'is': 0.0,'just': 0.5,'off': 0.5,'quick': 0.0,'show': 0.5,'this': 0.0,'to': 0.5}]
```

You can then add the dictionaries to your dataframe.

```
df['tf_idf'] = fully_indexed
```